# What does this Apache directive translate to?

Tags: apache-2.4

I noticed the following directives requested in one of our websites.

I am thinking it means that if a certain condition is met, do nothing.

The one I am interested in is `RewriteRule ^ -`  this is the "do nothing" piece of the logic. I am not able to see any reference to this even on apache site or probably I am not looking at the right place. The caret usually means the beginning of a string but in this case it means the entire request. I can only guess that the hypen stands for not performing anything.

```
RewriteCond <some_condition>
RewriteRule ^ -
```

Comment: What is the rest of the `RewriteRule`? It looks like you left off the last argument containing the flags. Without that, it really would do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless a rewrite flag is used this rule does nothing really. HTTPD documentation does cover the usage of dash.

> [- (dash)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
>   A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag needs to be applied without changing the path.

You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2102189/3886428) for an example of such a scenario.

[Regex cheatsheet.](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/)